# Check for same values in one arraylist and add amount to the respective value in second arraylist in android

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylists: `Percentlist` and `Amountlist`, what I want is check for the same value in the Percentlist and add respective Amountlist value(same position).

for e.g:
PercentList

- 20
- 30
- 40
- 30
- 20
- 30

AmountList:

- 50
- 60
- 100
- 70
- 120
- 90

I want result in two list like this:
Percent unique list

- 20
- 30
- 40

and AmountList with same values(from PercentList) total

- 170 (20 values from PercentList sum(50+120))
- 220 (30 values from PercentList sum(60+70+90))
- 100 (40 values from PercentList sum(100))

Please help

Comment: so what is your problem? I mean, where is your blocker? Where do you stop? What did you try out so far?

Comment: @RutvikBhatt he wants to sum values of AmountList at the indexes which correspond to the same value of PercentList. Like in PercentList there are 3 '20', so it wants the sum of those indexes but on the other array. Task is very simple, even if not clearly explained, but to me it sounds like "can you do my homework please please please" :)

Comment: Better you can use HashMap concept. But haspmap wont allow duplicate key. So please verify before use it

Comment: Please check i have updated the question.The problem is with the 2nd result List.

Comment: @Alessio You are a genius please do this homework for him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a `HashMap` like this. The keys of the map will be the percent and the mapped value will be the amount.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> percentList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(20,30,40,30,20,30));
    ArrayList<Integer> amountList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(50,60,100,70,120,90));
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < percentList.size();i++)
    {
        int percent = percentList.get(i);
        int amount = amountList.get(i);
        map.put(percent,(map.containsKey(percent) ? map.get(percent) : 0) + amount);
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> percentUniqueList = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    ArrayList<Integer> amountUniqueList = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

However, getting keys and values from `Map` does not conserve any order, be careful when using it as a list. I would suggest creating a class which has two properties, `percent` and `amount`, then make a list of this class instead of having two separate integer lists. Whenever you have multiple arrays of the same length and the elements of each arrays at the same index correspond to the different properties of the same object, you will be happy to make a single list of class which have multiple properties instead.